# Add a parameter to a class contained in one vector of that class

Tags: c++

I'm doing the BattleShip game and I need some help sorting out the ships. Here we go.

I have a Ship Class:

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship(char symbol, PositionChar position, char orientation, unsigned int size, unsigned int color);

private:

    unsigned int number;
    char symbol;
    PositionInt position;
    char orientation;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int color;
    string status;


};
```

and I have a Board class which contains:

```
vector <Ship> ships;
```

I need to load the info from a .txt:

```
tabuleiro: 10 x 10 
1 - Porta-avioes - 5 - P - Vermelho_claro 
1 - Fragata      - 4 – F - Magenta_claro 
2 - Cruzador     - 3 - C - Verde_claro   
3 - Submarino    - 2 - S - Castanho 
4 - Lancha       - 1 - L - Azul_claro
```

where I get the info using this:

```
while (getline(config, tmp)) {          

        config >> nr >> tmp >> nome >> tmp >> size >> tmp >> simb >> tmp >> cor; //de maneira analoga ao tabuleiro faz ignora os espaços e recolhe a info dos navios
        if (config.eof())
            break;
```

nr - number of ships
nome - name of the ship
size - size
simb - the char that represents it
cor - color

Now, my question is. I need to store all those ships (each line is a ship) and the info on the vector. Each element from the vector will contain all the info that I load from the txt.

How can I do that??

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Comment: You probably meant to write `std::istringstream iss(tmp); iss >> nr >> tmp >> ...`

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by overloading `operator>>` for your `ship` class:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Ship &s) { 
    std::string tmp;
    return is >> s.nr >> tmp 
              >> s.nome >> tmp 
              >> s.size >> tmp 
              >> s.simb >> tmp 
              >> s.cor;
}
```

This allows you to read data from a file directly into a `Ship` object, like:

```
std::ifstream in("yourfile.txt");
Ship some_ship;

in >> some_ship;
```

It also (like other stream extractors) returns a reference to the `istream` object you were reading from. This allows two things. The first is chaining operators, so you could read two (or more) items at once:

```
in >> ship_a >> ship_b;
```

It also means you can check whether a stream extraction succeeded or not:

```
if (in >> some_ship)
    // ...
```

...or do reading in a loop that will (for example) exit when you reach the end of a file:

```
while (in >> some_ship)
    process(some_ship);
```

The standard also includes an `istream_iterator` type that will use `operator>>` to read things via an iterator interface. You can use that to (for one example) read an entire file full of Ship objects, and use them to initialize a vector:

```
std::ifstream input("YourFilename.txt");
std::vector<Ship> ships { std::istream_iterator<Ship>(input),
                          std::istream_iterator<Ship>() };
```

This does have one shortcoming though: it implicitly assumes that as soon as you've read the end of one record, you'll have some white-space (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) and then immediately after that will be the record for the next `Ship` object. If your input file might instead contain some extra garbage at the end of a line (after all the fields for the ship object itself), you could instead read in a line of data, then use a `stringstream` to parse an object out of that line:

```
std::string s;
Ship temp;

while (std::getline(input, s)) {
    std::istringstream is(s);
    if (!is >> temp)
        break;
    ships.push_back(temp);
}
```

This allows you to throw away any excess data at the end of a line. You read the file a line at a time, and then parse the data you care about out from that line. When you've done that, you just ignore anything that's left and go on to the next line.

Comment: I didnt learn anything about operators yet. Do you think it is the best way to do it? :)
Thank you anyway

Comment: Best way, probably yes. Best way for someone learning the language, probably not. I'd try warzon's answer first. Much simpler.

Comment: @user4581301: So you're basically saying that he should practice using the language poorly, and somehow in the long term that's going to lead to his using the language well?

Comment: If you could just give me a brief explanation I'd appreciate, I'd like to improve a bit aswell.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm saying he's better off building on what he understands and using that to see further. The original draft of your answer was weak on what you were doing and why it was a better option, and that tends toward cargo cults, not learning. The current version solves that, and the OP sounds capable of looking up operator overloading on their own. They'll still have to figure out how to do it correctly and, depending on the course load, may or may not have the time.

Answer (score 1):

To directly address your concern here

```
ships.push_back(Ship(nr,nome,size,...))
```

This should be done in a loop for each ship.

Comment: Recommend editing to use the variables used by the OP here `config >> nr >> tmp >> nome >> tmp >> size >> tmp >> simb >> tmp >> cor;` instead of arg1 etc... to make what you're suggesting more obvious to the OP.

Comment: Not sure if the variables are in the right order as that in constructor. That's why I don't include them initially.

Comment: Point taken. Also worth noting that the  `ships.push_back...` can drop in right after `config >> nr >> tmp >> nome ...` in the OP's code.

Comment: ships.push_back(Ship(simb, position, ori, size, cor)); - request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘((Board*)this)->Board::ships’, which is of non-class type ‘int’ 
Why this does happen?

Comment: @Verance Often when a compiler cannot find the definition of a variable it assumes the variable to be an int. There is probably another  message stating that Board or Ship cannot be found or cannot be defined because of an error inside the definition. If the class cannot be found, you may have a missing header file or the call to `ships.push_back` is above the class definition and the class does not exist yet.

Comment: @user4581301 do you mind if I add you on skype just for few questions please?  I promise I wont bother :)

Comment: Not a skype person, I'm afraid.